# What's the right way to get .text from this pattern?

Tags: java, antlr

Consider the following pattern,

```
expression returns [String value]
    :  StringLiteral
    { $value = $StringLiteral.text; }

    |  IntegerLiteral
    { $value = $IntegerLiteral.text; }
    ;
```

Now I would like to merge the `String` and `Integer` rule into a single one,

```
expression returns [String value]
    :  (StringLiteral | IntegerLiteral)
    { 
    }
    ;
```

It's quite stupid to check if `$XXLiteral.text == null` and then get value from either of them.

Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
expression returns [String value]
    :  t=(StringLiteral | IntegerLiteral)
       { $value = $t.text; }
    ;
```

or:

```
expression returns [String value]
    :  (t=StringLiteral | t=IntegerLiteral)
       { $value = $t.text; }
    ;
```